# Reduce and FullSimplify don't reduce fully -- how to check if candidate solutions hold

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have a big system of equations and want to check if some candidate solutions hold.

Ideally, I want to have an expression that returns 'True' if my candidate solution hold and 'False' otherwise.

Based on previous posts, I decided to use `Reduce[my_equtions && candidate_solutions && assumptions_on_variables]`

However, Mathematica doesn't fully reduce the system to `True` / `False` -- even after using `FullSimplify`, some trivial terms remain in the output. Especially when `my_equations` are multiple, long equation, it is hard to find spot manually if the output should be true or not.

Consider as a MWE  the system $x a^2 + y b^2 + (-x - y) ab == 0$ with the assumption $y>x>1$ over the reals. We have candidate solutions $a=1/x$, $b=1/y$ , which clearly solve the system.

However,

```
Reduce[x a^2 + y b^2 + (-x - y) ab == 0 &&  a == 1/x && b == 1/y && 
   y > x > 1, {a, b}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

Outputs:

> 1 < x < y && ab == 1/(x y) && a == 1/x && b == 1/y

Ideally, I would get `True` or `candidate_solutions && assumptions_on_variables`. In any case, the part

> ab == 1/(x y)

should not be in there, as these terms become very annoying when the system of equations is large.

My questions:

1. How can I make `Reduce` to output simply `True` or `candidate_solutions && assumptions_on_variables`
2. Is there a better command to test if given candidate solutions fulfill a system of equations under certain assumptions?

Comment: Your `ab` is not the same as `a*b`. Typing `ab` without space is a separate symbol.

Comment: The canonical way to check a candidate solution is `eq=x*a^2+y*b^2+(-x-y)*a*b;candidate={a->1/x,b->1/y};eq/. candidate//Simplify`. Another useful command in this ballpark is `PossibleZeroQ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Simplify[
 x a^2 + y b^2 + (-x - y) a*b == 0, {a == 1/x, b == 1/y, y > x > 1}]
```

> `True`.

Answer (score 3):

Provide the conditions to FullSimplify too.

```
eq = x a^2 + y b^2 + (-x - y) a b == 0;

cond = a == 1/x && b == 1/y && y > x > 1;

Reduce[eq && cond, {a, b}, Reals] // FullSimplify[#, cond] &

(*   True   *)
```